# Populate 3rd drop down list using HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking to populate the third drop down list with a 1, 2, or 3 based on the selection from the first and second drop down using onchange if possible.  I have researched this for two days and haven't found an answer yet.

```js
    function populate(s1,s2){
     var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
     var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
     s2.innerHTML = "";
    
     if(s1.value == "317 Professional Liability Management Protection Program Coverages"){
      varS2 optionArray = ["|","n/a|N/A"];
     } else if(s1.value == "317 Professional Liability - Other than hospital, Healthcare, Physicians, Surgeons, and densits, and Management Protection Program"){
      var optionArray = ["|","n/a|N/A"];
     } else if(s1.value == "325 Special Classifications Liability"){
      var optionArray = ["|","products/completed|PRODUCTS/COMPLETED","all other|ALL OTHER"];
     }
     for(var option in optionArray){
      var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
      var newOption = document.createElement("option");
      newOption.value = pair[0];
      newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
      s2.options.add(newOption); 
     }
    }
```

```html
    <body>
    <h2>Type of Loss</h2>
    Choose Subline:
    <select id="slct1" name="slct1" onchange="populate(this.id,'slct2')">
      <option value=""></option>
    <option Value="317 Professional Liability Management Protection Program Coverages">317 Professional Liability Management Protection Program Coverages</option>
    <option Value="317 Professional Liability - Other than hospital, Healthcare, Physicians, Surgeons, and densits, and Management Protection Program">317 Professional Liability - Other than hospital, Healthcare, Physicians, Surgeons, and densits, and Management Protection Program</option>
    <option Value="325 Special Classifications Liability">325 Special Classifications Liability</option>
    <option Value="325 E-Commerce">325 E-Commerce</option>
    <option Value="332 Liquor Law Liability">332 Liquor Law Liability</option>
    <option Value="334 Premises/Operations Liability">334 Premises/Operations Liability</option>
    <option Value="335 Owners/Contractors Protective Liability">335 Owners/Contractors Protective Liability</option>
    <option Value="336 Products/Completed Operations Liability">336 Products/Completed Operations Liability</option>
    <option Value="342 Composite Large "a" Rated Risks">342 Composite Large "a" Rated Risks</option>
    <option Value="343 Composite Loss Rated Risks">343 Composite Loss Rated Risks</option>
    <option Value="345 All Other Composite Rated Risks:Premises/Operations – only coverage">345 All Other Composite Rated Risks:Premises/Operations – only coverage</option>
    <option Value="346 All Other Composite Rated Risks:Products/Completed Operations – only coverage">346 All Other Composite Rated Risks:Products/Completed Operations – only coverage</option>
    <option Value="347 All Other Composite Rated Risks:Premises/Operations and Products/Completed Operations coverage">347 All Other Composite Rated Risks:Premises/Operations and Products/Completed Operations coverage</option>
    <option Value="350 Pollution Liability">350 Pollution Liability</option>
    <option Value="360 Employment Related Practices Liability">360 Employment Related Practices Liability</option>
    <option Value="365 Product Withdrawal Coverage (ISO Endorsements CG 04 36 and CG 00 66 or company equivalent)">365 Product Withdrawal Coverage (ISO Endorsements CG 04 36 and CG 00 66 or company equivalent</option>
    <option Value="337 Farm and CGL Farm Liability Premises/Operations/Products (1998 Program)">337 Farm and CGL Farm Liability Premises/Operations/Products (1998 Program)</option>
    <option Value="338 Farm and CGL Farm Liability Premises/Operations CGL Liability (1998 Program)">338 Farm and CGL Farm Liability Premises/Operations CGL Liability (1998 Program)</option>
    <option Value="339 Farm and CGL Farm Liability Products CGL Liability (1998 Program)">339 Farm and CGL Farm Liability Products CGL Liability (1998 Program)</option>
    <option Value="334 Farm and CGL Farm Liability Premises/Operations Liability (pre-1998 Program)">334 Farm and CGL Farm Liability Premises/Operations Liability (pre-1998 Program)</option>
    <option Value="336 Farm and CGL Farm Liability Products/Completed Liability (pre-1998 Program)">336 Farm and CGL Farm Liability Products/Completed Liability (pre-1998 Program)</option>
    <option Value="366 Farm and CGL Farm Liability Limited Product Withdrawal Expense Coverage (ISO Endorsement FL 04 02 or company equivalent)">366 Farm and CGL Farm Liability Limited Product Withdrawal Expense Coverage (ISO Endorsement FL 04 02 or company equivalent)</option>
    </select>
    <div>
    Choose Products/Completed, All Other:
    <select id="slct2" name="slct2" onchange="populate(this.id,'slct2','slct3')"></select>
    </div>
    Choose BI, PD, Other:
    <select id="slct3" name="slct3"></select>
    </body>
```

Comment: on line 11 you have a typo: `vars2 optionArray`  ->  `var optionArray`

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you want. Can you provide more detail ?
The second drop list change depending on the change of the first... do you want the third to change when the second list change ?

Comment: Hi Sylvain, that is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems is that your function (populate) has only two parameters.
But consider rethinking the whole business logic a little, you're going to lose track very soon with this approach.

Comment: my business need is to make sure that coders are selecting the correct coding criteria based off these drop downs.  Making it very difficult to code the type of loss incorrectly, I'm having a hard time thinking of a different approach since I am very limited in the coding skills.  My first approach involved Excel with data validation which got very messy very quickly.

Comment: Didn't want to sound like judging you.  Sure it's not easy, especially not for a non-experienced coder. But if you can (for example) get all possible dropdowns ready on a single page, you're all set - from there, it's only a matter of hiding/showing <select> tags.  I mean, IF I understood right what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with dkellner on the fact that you might want to re-think all the process.

The main problem you have is that as you have only one function populate and as this function erase all the second drop list content, you will never know what was its value.
You should try using two different functions : 
 - `populateS2(s1) {...}` would be called when the s1 value change, erase s2 and s3 and set the s2 options.
 - `populateS3 (s1, s2) {...}` would be called when s2 change, erase s3 and set s3's options according to s1 and s2's values.